# Using inline "if helper" with logical operator in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So basically, I just want to add class **active** if **index** is equal to **0**.

```
{{#each posts as |post index|}}
  <div class="item {{ 'add active class here if index is 0' }}">
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I know using this code, `{{if index == 0 'active'}}` won't work because built-in **if helper** in ember doesn't support logical operators. [Ember Conditionals](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/templates/conditionals/)

So what are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: `<div class="item {{if index '' 'active' }}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon.

Also [ember-math-helpers](https://github.com/shipshapecode/ember-math-helpers) is good for math operations.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks.